# Double time specification in file in laravel api

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I am making api's in laravel and getting `2021-01-30T10:30:17.704 05:30` from `$request->followup` and i have column in database named followup having datetime datatype. But it's giving me following error.

```
Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidFormatException: Could not parse '2021-01-30T10:30:17.704 05:30': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2021-01-30T10:30:17.704 05:30) at position 24 (0): Double time specification in file D:\xampp2\htdocs\synocrm-baid\rest-apis\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php on line 188
```

I tried to change format like

```
$followupDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s A',strtotime($request->followup));
```

My modal having

```
@property Carbon|null $followup
```

Comment: If 5:30 is a timezone, it sounds like the + has been URL decoded: you should have 2021-01-30T10:30:17.704+05:30 and should encode the value so you don' t loose the +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$request->followup` is appending datetime with datetime

**Original Value: 2021-01-30T10:30:17.704 05:30**

**Datetime: 2021-01-30T10:30:17.704**

**Time: 05:30**

As we can see, there is two Time (05:30 and 10:30:17), because of which the `strtotime()` cannot convert the value.

In order to fix the problem,

1. Send the value as time time only (2021-01-30T10:30:17.704) instead of two times Time attribute
2. If you have no control over request value, you can retrieve only date value like:

   ```
   $dateValue = explode(' ', $request->followup)[0];

   $followupDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s A',strtotime($dateValue));

   Or Using Carbon

   $followupDate = Carbon::parse($dateValue);
   ```

I would not recommend option 2 because it creates problems and confusion for other devs.

Comment: I tried second option but still facing same issue

Comment: Could you paste the value of $dateValue

Comment: $dateValue returning 2021-01-30T10:30:17.704

Comment: The same value is working for me. Please do try again. For easiness, I also added carbon option as well.

Comment: Working for me i assigned value into $request->followup instead of followupdate then it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

2021-01-30T10:30:17.704 05:30

It does not seem to valid timestamp. For parsing, it should be the valid timestamp or date.